# java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space while uploading large file via ZuulFilter

Tags: java, netflix-zuul

I am using "zuul-core-1.0.28" module for routing purpose in my gateway class. 
While uploading couple of file of size 50 MB each, "java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space" exception is thrown from one of the Routing class while forwarding the request to the appropriate api. While forwarding, ZuulFilter tries to parse the request body(chunk of file in this case) and that's where its failed and throw below exception

```
Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
    at java.lang.StringCoding$StringDecoder.decode(StringCoding.java:149) ~[na:1.8.0_51]
    at java.lang.StringCoding.decode(StringCoding.java:193) ~[na:1.8.0_51]
    at java.lang.String.<init>(String.java:414) ~[na:1.8.0_51]
    at java.lang.String.<init>(String.java:479) ~[na:1.8.0_51]
    at com.netflix.zuul.http.HttpServletRequestWrapper.parseRequest(HttpServletRequestWrapper.java:167) ~[zuul-core-1.0.28.jar:na]
    at com.netflix.zuul.http.HttpServletRequestWrapper.getInputStream(HttpServletRequestWrapper.java:225) ~[zuul-core-1.0.28.jar:na]
    at javax.servlet.ServletRequest$getInputStream$1.call(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at SimpleHostRoutingFilter.j(SimpleHostRequest.groovy:318) ~[spider.jar:na]
    at SimpleHostRoutingFilter$getRequestBody$2.callCurrent(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at SimpleHostRoutingFilter.run(SimpleHostRequest.groovy:175) ~[spider.jar:na]
    at com.netflix.zuul.ZuulFilter.runFilter(ZuulFilter.java:112) ~[zuul-core-1.0.28.jar:2.4.4]
    at com.netflix.zuul.FilterProcessor.processZuulFilter(FilterProcessor.java:197) ~[zuul-core-1.0.28.jar:2.4.4]
    at com.netflix.zuul.FilterProcessor.runFilters(FilterProcessor.java:161) ~[zuul-core-1.0.28.jar:2.4.4]
    at com.netflix.zuul.FilterProcessor.route(FilterProcessor.java:120) ~[zuul-core-1.0.28.jar:2.4.4]
    at com.netflix.zuul.ZuulRunner.route(ZuulRunner.java:84) ~[zuul-core-1.0.28.jar:2.4.4]
    at com.netflix.zuul.http.ZuulServlet.route(ZuulServlet.java:111) ~[zuul-core-1.0.28.jar:na]
    at com.netflix.zuul.http.ZuulServlet.service(ZuulServlet.java:77) ~[zuul-core-1.0.28.jar:na]
```

I know, particularly this issue is been posted here number of times and
have increased JVM heap size up to 1GB but still facing the problem. More over I am sure in production it will fail in the first place as there will be thousands of request will come very frequently and increasing memory wont help much.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: While your question has part of the answer to it, it is also required to `base line your application` and arrive to a suggestible memory tuning that is required to have supported heap size rather than _just deciding on a couple of tests with 1GB heap max size_, in my opinion.

Comment: Thanks for your comment @Rao, my application is all about document management (like DrobpBox). So it is expected that a lot of document will be uploaded/downloaded parallelly in the system and if the request processing fails at the gateway level(gateway as in -incoming request  before hitting the system, we do some processing to the request and then forward the request to the system), I don't know how increasing memory will help to the cause. And FYI, those couple of test failing everytime.

Comment: This really looks like a failure on zuul's part to properly manage large forwarding requests. I think it should be changed to write large requests to file before forwarding, and not require the entire contents to be in memory.  This still happens with zuul-core-1.3.0 (spring-boot 1.5.10)